# How to get push id uniquely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm building a forum, and I'm in the step of views. I have this (simplified) code:

```
 //Setting Views
//Adding Them..
$scope.views = $firebaseObject(refService.ref().child("Topics"))
refService.ref().child("Topics").once("value", function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key();
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        if(childData.DateCreated == $stateParams.DATE && childData.Email == $stateParams.EMAIL){
            refService.ref().child("Topics").child(childData.pushKey).child("Views").child(currentAuth.uid).set({
                Views : true
            })
        }
    })
})

//Viewing them
$scope.viewableView = $firebaseObject(refService.ref().child("Topics"))
```

As you can see adding the views was pretty easy job. And I did it correctly. The problem is with displaying the number of views, and I have to do it using AngularFire's `$firebaseObject`, or `$firebaseArray`... Here is the structure in database:

```
{
  "Topics" : {
    "-KG9rDNLZksJDiLfAXwH" : {
      "Avatar" : "http://cs624223.vk.me/v624223037/2b1bb/GRTKddkmXiw.jpg",
      "DateCreated" : 1461544873669,
      "Email" : "abogale2@gmail.com",
      "Title" : "Check",
      "UID" : "3caf2136-7a2d-4ae4-a4a9-119f2b08133c",
      "Username" : "BruhBrhu",
      "Value" : "Check",
      "Views" : {
        "3caf2136-7a2d-4ae4-a4a9-119f2b08133c" : {
          "Views" : true
        }
      },
      "pushKey" : "-KG9rDNLZksJDiLfAXwH"
    }
  },
  "UserAuthInfo" : {
    "3caf2136-7a2d-4ae4-a4a9-119f2b08133c" : {
      "BronzeBadge" : 0,
      "Description" : "Just a wierd 15 year old coder...",
      "Email" : "abogale2@gmail.com",
      "GoldBadge" : 0,
      "Image" : "http://cs624223.vk.me/v624223037/2b1bb/GRTKddkmXiw.jpg",
      "Moderator" : false,
      "Password" : "KfUcQ1yedOi1gEnGP6i1KQ==",
      "PlatinumBadge" : 0,
      "SilverBadge" : 0,
      "UID" : "3caf2136-7a2d-4ae4-a4a9-119f2b08133c",
      "Username" : "BruhBrhu"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I used `push()`, to get the topic.. My Concern now is how to view the topics! Please Help! I can't think of a "algorithm" to do it!

Mind you, all of the topics have unique ID's. I have to get the specific ID The user is in.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Can anyone anwser?? Or is this an impossible task @FrankvanPuffelen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
 refService.ref().child("Topics").once("value", function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                      var key = childSnapshot.key();
                      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                      if(childData.DateCreated == $stateParams.DATE && childData.Email == $stateParams.EMAIL){
                            refService.ref().child("Topics").child(childData.pushKey).child("Views").on("value", function(snapshot){
                                console.log(snapshot.numChildren())
                                $scope.countViews = snapshot.numChildren();
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
```

I dont know how but somehow $scope.countViews, became three way binded to my HTML, so it actually shows!

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting keys inside an object, which the [Firebase documentation explicitly recommends against](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html).

But it can work once you realize that you can also add methods to the scope:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['firebase']);

app.constant('FB_URL', 'https://yours.firebaseio.com/');
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(FB_URL, $scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FB_URL);
  $scope.topics = $firebaseArray(ref.child('Topics'));
  $scope.getCount = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
  };
});
```

And the view:

```
<body ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
  <ol><li ng-repeat='topic in topics'>{{topic.Title}} - {{topic.Username}} - {{getCount(topic.Views)}}</li></ol>
</body>
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dapoga/edit?html,js,output